# Traverse to a chat reply in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a Swipe to Reply feature on my chat app with flutter. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojBSygkVaNo) helped me a lot in achieving that. However, the issue i have is I need to navigate to the message I replied to when clicking on the Reply widget (just like the way Whatsapp works).

I tried wrapping around a `GestureDetector` and `onPanUpdate` to get the `DragUpdateDetails` to get the position but it didn't work effectively.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: have you solve this?

Comment: yes I did find a way

Comment: Can you share how you solved this problem. Thanks